# Running GBM on H2O Flow produces job failure: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, h2o, gbm

running an H2O Flow I've already successfully run in the past on a Mac OS with the following configuration:

```
04-18 22:50:02.722 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: ----- H2O started  -----
04-18 22:50:02.723 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Build git branch: rel-wolpert
04-18 22:50:02.723 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Build git hash: 6903ba4b4cfcd912f15cf61965f88bb13bbc4890
04-18 22:50:02.723 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Build git describe: jenkins-3.18.0.3-6-g6903ba4
04-18 22:50:02.723 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Build project version: 3.18.0.4 (latest version: 3.18.0.7)
04-18 22:50:02.723 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Build age: 1 month and 10 days
04-18 22:50:02.723 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Built by: 'jenkins'
04-18 22:50:02.723 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Built on: '2018-03-08 19:15:57'
04-18 22:50:02.723 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Watchdog Build git branch: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.724 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Watchdog Build git hash: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.724 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Watchdog Build git describe: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.724 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Watchdog Build project version: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.724 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Watchdog Built by: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.724 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Watchdog Built on: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.724 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: XGBoost Build git branch: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.724 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: XGBoost Build git hash: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.725 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: XGBoost Build git describe: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.725 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: XGBoost Build project version: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.725 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: XGBoost Built by: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.725 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: XGBoost Built on: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.725 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git branch: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.725 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git hash: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.725 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git describe: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.726 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build project version: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.726 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: KrbStandalone Built by: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.726 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: KrbStandalone Built on: (unknown)
04-18 22:50:02.726 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Processed H2O arguments: []
04-18 22:50:02.726 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Java availableProcessors: 4
04-18 22:50:02.726 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Java heap totalMemory: 245.5 MB
04-18 22:50:02.726 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Java heap maxMemory: 10.67 GB
04-18 22:50:02.726 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Java version: Java 1.8.0_162 (from Oracle Corporation)
04-18 22:50:02.726 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: JVM launch parameters: [-Xmx12g]
04-18 22:50:02.726 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: OS version: Mac OS X 10.12.6 (x86_64)
04-18 22:50:02.726 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: Machine physical memory: 16.00 GB
04-18 22:50:02.727 192.168.0.11:54321    684    main      INFO: X-h2o-cluster-id: 1524102601065
```

My dataset has around 600k observations and ~60 features.
When building a simple GBM model with CV5 the job stops with the following trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hex.Model$Parameters.read_unlock_frames(Model.java:331)
    at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:209)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1263)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

it always stops at 84% progress.

any clue why and what to do?

thanks
Carmelo